# Writing factory method in base class

Tags: c++

```
class Base {
 public:
   static std::unique_ptr<Base> CreateBase();
}

class Factory {
public:
  static std::unique_ptr<Base> CreateBase();
}
```

We can either declare the factory method in the base class or we can create a separate class and write the factory method inside it. Which one is better and why?

Comment: The first one should be static method.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude corrected.

Comment: In a fuller example, you'd construct child objects in your factory method based on some argument (e.g., a string). It goes without saying that you shouldn't pollute the base class with information about derived classes, so do not put the method there.

Comment: The first option requires the `Base` to know about classes derived from it and this often turns out to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

You can also declare the factory as a free function `std::unique_ptr<Base> CreateBase()` a.k.a [`std::make_unique<Base>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Answer (score 0):

In my very humble opionion the "create" is a function that naturally belongs to the factory. The factory creates something.

It can be implemented in any way. But still I do see it as a part of the factory.

You could also use a more sophisticated solution. With the class to be created defined in a very general manner and using a hybrid approach.

Please see example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the factory with an initializer list
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };

    // Add a new entry for the factory
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```